# strange angular click issue - filter & nested clicks on table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, zurb-foundation, angularjs-filter

so I'm experiencing a strange issue with angular in foundation for apps. (all code below)

I have a table of data with a filter object (visual bar of form elements linked to a single scope object) on a page (all within one controller). This includes a `select` of three options to filter the table by completed status (all,complete, incomplete);

Each row is `ng-repeat`ed and has an `ng-click` attached to highlight the row (for readability purposes). I then have in the last `td` of each row a styled checkbox to mark the row as "complete".

When I load the page and click a "complete" checkbox i can see my service function update the server and local websql file. if i select a filter check box (say direction) and click a "complete" check box it works;

It stops working when i filter the list using the "complete" filter select drop down; I can see the check box get checked and the scope digests but the check function is never called; any ideas?

CODE:

```js
//CONTROLLER

  .controller('tableShow', function($scope, $state, $http, dataService, $filter) {

  $scope.list = {};
  $scope.data = function() {
    console.log('filter'); //<-- SHOWS IN CONSOLE ON HIGHLIGHT OR CLICK OF COMPLETE REGARDLESS OF FUNCTION BEING CALLED;
    return $filter('filter')(Object.values(dataService.data), $scope.list);
  };

  $scope.headers = ["date", "t_id", "type", "code", "desc", "io"]; // used to only show required headers

  // LIST MANAGEMENT

  $scope.sortedBy = 'date';
  $scope.reversed = true;

  $scope.setSort = function(col) {
    $scope.reversed = ($scope.sortedBy == col ? !$scope.reversed : false);
    $scope.sortedBy = col;
  };

  //MISC FN
  $scope.highlight = function(e) {
    var row = e.target.tagName === 'tr' ? e.target : utils.getClosest(e.target, 'tr'),
      table = utils.getClosest(row, 'tbody'),
      preHl = table.querySelectorAll('tr[highlight]'),
      highlighted = row.hasAttribute('highlight');


    if (preHl.length > 0) {
      for (var i = preHl.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        preHl[i].removeAttribute('highlight');
      }
    }

    if (!highlighted)
      row.setAttribute('highlight', '');
  };


  $scope.unCheck = function(e) {

    console.log(e);
    var input = e.target,
      lastVal = input.parentNode.checked,
      model = input.getAttribute('ng-model').split('.');

    console.log(input.value, input.parentNode.checked);
    if (input.value !== input.parentNode.checked) {
      input.parentNode.checked = input.value;
      return;
    }

    input.checked = false;
    input.parentNode.checked = '';

    if (model.length == 1)
      delete $scope[model[0]];
    else if (model.length == 2)
      delete $scope[model[0]][model[1]];
    else if (model.length == 3)
      delete $scope[model[0]][model[1]][model[2]];
    else
      alert('There was an error matching the data model!');

  };

  $scope.complete = function(e, row) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // added the above as thought the click might be bubbling to highlight

    console.log('SUBMITTING', e, row); // does not show if complete is set
    var input = e.target,
      lastVal = input.parentNode.checked,
      newVal = input.value,
      sub = input.checked ? 1 : 0,
      _id = angular.copy(row.id), // thought this may be the problem but didnt help;
      data = {
        update: {
          data: [{
            id: _id,
            completed: sub
          }]
        }
      };

    input.disabled = true;

    sendData(data)
      .then(updated, failed);

    function updated() {

      if (input.value !== input.parentNode.checked) {
        input.parentNode.checked = input.value;
      } else {
        input.checked = false;
        input.parentNode.checked = '';
      }

      row.completed = sub;
      input.disabled = false;
    }

    function failed() {
      if (input.value == input.parentNode.checked) {
        input.parentNode.checked = input.value;
      } else {
        input.checked = false;
        input.parentNode.checked = '';
      }

      input.disabled = false;
    }
  };
});
```

HTML

```html
<section class="grid-content vertical">
  <form name="Form" class="grid-block vertical" ng-submit="">
    <fieldset name="ListSelect">
      <legend>Filter</legend>
      <div class="grid-block wrap">
        <div class="grid-content small-3">
          <div class="checker grid-block small-up-2">
            <input id="IN" name="io" type="radio" ng-model="list.io" value="IN" ng-click="unCheck($event)">
            <label for="IN" onclick="" class="grid-content noscroll">
              <span class="corners"></span> IN
            </label>
            <input id="OUT" name="io" type="radio" ng-model="list.io" value="OUT" ng-click="unCheck($event)">
            <label for="OUT" onclick="" class="grid-content noscroll">
              <span class="corners"></span> OUT
            </label>
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-content small-3">
          <div class="checker grid-block small-up-2">
            <input id="TYPE1" name="type" type="radio" ng-model="list.type" value="type1" ng-click="unCheck($event)">
            <label for="TYPE1" onclick="" class="grid-content noscroll">
              <span class="corners"></span> TYPE1
            </label>
            <input id="TYPE2" name="type" type="radio" ng-model="list.type" value="type2" ng-click="unCheck($event)">
            <label for="TYPE2" onclick="" class="grid-content noscroll">
              <span class="corners"></span> TYPE2
            </label>
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-content small-3">
          <select name="complete" ng-model="list.complete">
            <option value="" selected>All</option>
            <option value="1">Completed</option>
            <option value="0">InComplete</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <aside class="small-12 grid-block corners large vertical">
      <div class="grid-block data ddLine">
        <div class="grid-content data">
          <table class="responsive" id="inventoryList">
            <thead>
              <th ng-repeat="v in headers" ng-hide="(v == 'type' && list.type) ">
                <label ng-click="setSort(v)">
                  {{v | addSpace}}
                  <i class="fa fa-fw" ng-class="{'fa-sort-down': reversed && v == sortedBy, 'fa-sort-up': !reversed && v == sortedBy, 'fa-sort': v != sortedBy}"></i>
                </label>
              </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="anim-4" ng-click="highlight($event);" ng-repeat="r in data() | orderBy:sortedBy:reversed" ng-class="r.disabled == 1 ? 'disabledRow' : ''">
                <td ng-repeat="v in headers" class="nowrap" ng-hide="(v == 'type' && list.type)">
                  {{ v == 'date' ? (r[v] | dateShow) : (r[v] || '-')}}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="checker grid-block small-up-2">
                    <input id="complete-{{r.id}}" type="checkbox" name="complete" ng-model="r.complete" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="completed($event, r);">
                    <label for="complete-{{r.id}}" class="grid-content noscroll">
                      <span class="corners"></span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </form>
</section>
```

NOTES:

- no jQuery exists in this app
- i am aware that adding DOM attributes in a controller is considered bad practice ( i assure you this is not the problem, i have checked)
- I have to use `Object.values` as my data structure does not match angulars' array of objects structure; (my own fault too late to
  change!);
- I have cut out irrelevant code and classes to shrink down the size of this question;

EDIT
After some thought I think this may be caused by the filtering of the list & the model for the "complete" being linked to the row; in short changing the model of the row by clicking the complete checkbox causes the list filter to drop that row before the function is called; Although i'm not sure of a way around this as i'm still learning the angular ropes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My eyes sting. Your code is a million miles away from the Angular best practices... I can't digest it!

Comment: Constructive criticism would be helpful as opposed to a general 'well that's wrong' or 'heres a link!'. @Vi100 are you referring to js or html?

Comment: You're heavily manipulating DOM inside your controllers. Angular is just about the opposite... But as indicated by @MA-Maddin this is a hardly verifiable code. The only chance we have to give you an advise about it is making a "mental exercise" of what it's suppossed to do, but it's difficult because you're beating the fundamentals of the framework. Seriously, you should have to revise the concepts of "binding", "model" and "template" before going on with this. Your code will become less complicated. Sorry I cannot be more explicit, but is all about fundamentals.

Comment: Ok i appreciate the elaboration and understand that this is alot of code and no visuals. I did try to explain as much as i could prior to the code. I do have one more question if you have time please, other than adding a visual attribute (nothing to do with the angular data model) from within the controller how am i heavily manipulating the DOM? afaik the code i posted above only affects the DOM via model / scope values.

Comment: For example, you're manipulating the inputs (ckeckboxes) directly, and not using their model... Also, you could highlight a row using a class, you don't need an attribute for that (or I can't imagine your use case). Anyway, as I told you it's all about Angular fundamentals.

Comment: I just about screamed when I saw an `if else` loop with `delete $scope[model[0]][model[1]][model[2]];`... that's about as far from angular practices as you can get, and completely unmaintainable.  What happens when you change the order of these items, or change how many items you are working with?  Plus, it seems like this kind of logic of maintaining a separate list for the checked items was the cause of the problem to begin with;  you may have found a fix for your problem, but it just exposes a greater flaw in the overall design....

Answer (score 0):

As I Thought, this WAS linked to the filter in `$scope.data` being called during a digest before the click function got called.

The culprit was the checkbox for "complete" having the ngClick and ngModel attached at the same time. When the list is filtered by "complete" and the checkbox clicked, it toggled the rows "complete" value triggering the digest, meaning the row was filtered out of the list before the ngClick gets called.

As the `input[checkbox]` was hidden and a graphical one within the `label` replaced it, i simply detached the `label` from the checkbox removing the `for` attr and moved the `ngClick` to the `label` itself. Now the row is only updated when the backend has been;